# JsonNet.Deserialize<T> NullReferenceException

Tags: json.net

Using

```
<PackageReference Include="Json.NET" Version="1.0.16" />
```

I have some JSON that looks like

```
{
    "links": [ { ... }, ... ]
}
```

Obviously the ellipsis is for brevity.

This deserializes well into a model type that only has three properties, of which only one is `links` the other two aren't used yet, I have removed them to test and it makes no difference to my problem.

The links property on my model type is a generic collection `HyperlinkCollection<TLink>`.

It all works until I change the JSON to this.

```
{
    "about": {
      "version": "1",
      "healthMessage": "Healthy"
    },
    "links": [ ... ]
}
```

Then I get this error.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Json.Net.JsonParser.FromJson(Type type)
   at Json.Net.JsonParser.FromJson(Type type)
   at Json.Net.JsonNet.Deserialize[T](String json, IJsonConverter[] converters)
```

Firstly it doesn't seem right to me that a naked NullRef should come from a library.

Secondly, I thought the extraneous member `about` would be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised that someone has added a `Json.NET` package to NuGet.org which isn't `Newtonsoft.Json`.

I switched to use the real thing and its all working.

Comment: Was just about to mention the same thing after googling the package version. Looks like the wrong package